# Is there a way to open a context menu containing some icons menu items horizontally on the top of target element in angular?

Tags: angular, contextmenu, primeng

I have a diagram editor page where I want to open a flying toolbar(Here flying toolbar means it can be opened on any shape present in the editor similar to context menu) by clicking over graphical elements of editor to perform some operation. But it should be opened horizontally at the top of the element on left click unlike normal context menu.

any idea how to do it?

I have tried to use prime ng context menu for the same but I didn't find a way to make it horizontal

[Attached picture is what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpHze.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve by overriding primeng css classes `.p-contextmenu` and `.p-contextmenu .p-menuitem` in **styles.css**

You can find the example [here in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-contextmenu-demo-s88lpg).

```css
    .p-contextmenu {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .p-contextmenu .p-menuitem {
        float: left;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Berkin for your answer. Can we open the context menu at the top of mouse pointer? With this it is opening below the mouse pointer.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. As I know, you cannot change the position of context menu.